# Django Media url returns 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: python, django, media-url

I have a django project.
In order to set up my media url, I followed the django doc [Django doc - Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/):

> For example, if your MEDIA_URL is defined as /media/, you can do this by adding the following snippet to your urls.py:
>
> from django.conf import settings
>   from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> urlpatterns = [
>      # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
>   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

my **settings.py**:

```
# ....
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
# ...
MEDIA_URL_REL = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = BASE_URL + MEDIA_URL_REL
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
 # ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My uploaded files are found in media root, but when I access media url [ *http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/proof/img.pdf*]for it, it returns **HTTP 404 NOT FOUND**.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: yes, I had 'DEBUG = True'

Comment: try printing BASE_DIR and check if BASE_DIR/media is your actual media directory

Comment: Why are you using `BASE_URL`?

Comment: @Darshan: I did, and they are ok

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev , I always do so, to be easier to redirect from a view.

Comment: You don't need `BASE_URL` to redirect from view.

Comment: I know, but i had cases where I have to return an url as a response data like:  ` {.. 'action': settings.BASE_URL + urlresolvers.reverse(...)}` , so if i have multiple cases like this, it's better to keep BASE_URL, because if in the future it changes, you have to change it in one place. 
Do you think that this could be the problem ? I don't think it matters, it's the same way if i have `MEDIA_URL = BASE_URL + MEDIA_URL_RELz` or `MEDIA_URL =  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/" `

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please don't make any url with hard coded. This is more than bad practice.

`BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'`

You can't write like that.

Your solution,

#### settings.py

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

#### urls.py

`urlpatterns = [
  .......
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Hope this works.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it works for some images and in others it returns 404 not found. Do you know why?

Comment: I having the same issue with a Django 1.8 simplest app with just some static pages and no database etc. Nothing in media loads. Example : http://localhost:8000/media/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css - but the pages like http://localhost:8000/about loads.